# Cancel adding an order item at any point

Tags: commerce

I think I have an quite unusual usecase.

In my commerce installation, there are two possible carts for each user. "buy" and "sell". Each product has two variations, also called "buy" and "sell". Commerce is configured to add those variations to the corresponding carts.

Now the problem: There should always only be one cart for the user. Either of type "buy" or type "sell".

### Example:

The user has just added item "Apple" to his "buy" cart. Now he tries to add "Bananas" to his "sell" cart. This should be aborted/cancelled.

---

I have seen there are events for the add to cart, but those run when the item has been added and the cart was created if I'm not mistaken.

Are there any events that would help me in that usecase? Or do I need to somehow hook myself into any possible form to prevent the adding? Cause I'm using a combination of the module "variation cart form", "add to cart link" and a custom form.

thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah I'd say the easiest way would be to hook into the add to cart form and add your own validation function. In there you could check the carts and then return an error to prevent the item being added?

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there are any events that would help, looking at

```
Drupal\commerce_cart\Event\CartEvents
```

as you said they all run after an item has been added, i think your best bet is to alter the add to cart form and query the other cart for items.